# How to select unique elements in a column of the table in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

If there are duplicated elements in a column, how to select the unique elements in a column in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1):

The function [distinct](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/d/distinct.html) is used to remove the duplicated elements.

```py
t=table(3 1 2 2 3 as x);
select distinct x from t;
```

Result:

[image]